# Erro Connection Root VM Instance Computer Engine Google Cloud?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have Install SDK then log in (gcloud auth login). I can't log in SSH VM google cloud?

with message "CommandError: Logging into instances as root is not recommended. If you actually wish to log in as root, you must provide the --permit_root_ssh flag."

how to log in SSH root??

I can not log in to the VM Instances. I look login VM Instances https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart#setup

$gcutil ssh

then message "CommandError: Logging into instances as root is not recommended. If you actually wish to log in as root, you must provide the --permit_root_ssh flag."

I have log in
ssh ..
Massage" Host key verification failed."

So how to log

Answer (score 1):

You usually don't login as root to your GCE instances. Instead, you log in as an unprivileged user, and then use [`sudo`](http://www.sudo.ws/) when root privileges are required.

Comment: how to log in a user? If I have not made ​​a root user without logging in? 
I have always been denied her case to go to SSH. when I have been following with google document

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to run the gcutil tools as a non-privileged (i.e. not root) user on your local machine.  [The default GCE image is designed to encourage running only the commands you need to as root](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances#root), and disables root login by default.

If you decide you want to login in directly as root, there are (brief) instructions at the above link.

Comment: Would you add info how to enable root ssh? I see `PermitRootLogin no` in `sshd_config`. I think it is set by the google cloud agent because I have `user-data` instructing `cloud-init` **not** to do that.